# Kubernetes how to divise volume of persistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes

I have a persistentVolumeClaim fix (50go) and I wouldlike to divise this volume in 3 parts :

```
volumes:
        - name: part1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myDisk
        - name: part2
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myDisk
        - name: part3
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myDisk
```

Can I edit in this config file like : storage for part1 = 10go or part2 = 30go ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here as far as i understand you should create. three different persistence volume with different size like,

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: part1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi

Comment: @Mr.J Oh ok... so it's impossible to divise a PersistentVolumeClaim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent volumes or claims can’t be divided. Also, there is a 1:1 relationship between Volumes and Claims. You can, however, create multiple PVs/PVCs from a storage classes. See the following example for reference. I am creating three PVCs from one storage class. It will also create relevant PVs for me as well. In case of `hostpath` SC, it will use `/var/lib/docker` folder for storage by default. If you want to control the path, you will have to create the PVs yourself as well.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: part1
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: part2
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: part3
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Mi
```

Comment: Are you sure all 3 PVCs will be provisioned?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The PVC were created but not bound. PVs and PVCs seems to have 1:1 mapping. I have updated the answer to reflect your feedback.